# Unable to open appium

Tags: appium, python-appium, appium-desktop

Whenever i am clicking on appium its not opening
[image: Whenever i am clicking on appium its not opening]

**Appium is not opening in my system? Can anyone help me with this. ERROR MESSAGE - The Application Appium can't be opened**

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the context menu: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/open-a-mac-app-from-an-unidentified-developer-mh40616/12.0/mac/12.0 .